# Views gives wrong path

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I use Drupal Commerce module and Views Slideshow. In Fields I have this `(Products referenced by field_product) Commerce Product: Product Image` field and in Relationships `Content: Product`, it is an image field and selecting Link image to: Content it links it to admin/commerce/products/4 when the product display for user is node/5

[image]

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is only a google search away..

https://drupal.org/node/1108180